# Are there any good sites to view screenshots of actual web applications?

Tags: user-interface, screenshot

I am looking for some websites that have **actual** screenshots of web applications, as well as, things like login screens, grids/tables, edit forms, CSS examples and so on.

I find that **looking** at other applications helps with the creative process when designing and styling my own applications.

I am able to get quite a few by googling for images but would like to see what other sites I may be missing.

**Example**

I'm just looking for one stop websites ... for example, I am working on adding paging to a table of data ... would love to go to one place and see how other sites/applications are doing it.

**Here is a compiled list of links so far:**

- http://www.gooeytemplates.com/
- http://uipatternfactory.com/
- http://ui-patterns.com/
- http://www.welie.com/patterns/index.php
- http://www.smileycat.com/design_elements/
- http://cssremix.com/
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/
- http://miniajax.com/
- http://patterntap.com/

Answer (score 5):

This one could help: [http://patterntap.com](http://patterntap.com/)

Comment: Hi Milan, obsolete link? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[MiniAjax](http://miniajax.com/) is a showroom of ajax snippets/solutions embeddable in web_apps. It's owned by John Reisig (the guy who created JQuery) but he's selling it. I guess this is better than static screenshots since you can see features in action.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for styling tips, then you might check out [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/).

Specifically, you might do a search on that site for pagination. Here's a link that I got when I did that:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/11/16/pagination-gallery-examples-and-good-practices/

Answer (score 1):

What type of "web application"?

Because there's a lot of online application you can use. Just think about those you've use today. Did you read your e-mail online? Have any social-app account?

Comment: I'm just looking for one stop websites ... for example, I am working on adding paging to a table of data ... would love to go to one place and see how other sites are doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for inspiration checkout [CSSRemix](http://www.cssremix.com) (Like the [TheFWA](http://www.thefwa.com) but for HTML/CSS instead of Flash).

Answer (score 1):

I found some more sites:

- http://www.gooeytemplates.com/
- http://uipatternfactory.com/
- http://ui-patterns.com/
- http://www.welie.com/patterns/index.php

I think I am going to start compiling a list in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Found this very cool website http://www.smileycat.com/design_elements/.  They have screen shots of login forms, footers, headers and so on!  Good stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is! http://browsershots.org/

Have fun! :)

Comment: Maybe he should re-write the question so you actually understands what it means. My answer, answered the topic and the overall blurry question :)

Comment: You do not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found [www.themeforest.net](http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/admin-skins) that has administration skins that could be used for user interface design.

Answer (score 0):

Infragistics just created a website dedicated to user interface design patterns that have some nice images of specific functionality.  You can find it at http://quince.infragistics.com/.